# Chrome - "Trying to load script from unauthenticated sources"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm having some issues with my website. It runs and renders just fine, but I get the blocked scripts icon at the top right of the address bar. I don't want users to see this pop up when visiting the site. I can press "load unsafe scripts", which will make it go away but then my site is no longer https. I've tried rearranging the lines and tried other things as well in my html but I can't seem to find a solution. 
The site uses bootstrap as well as 2 of my own CSS files and 1 JavaScript file.
Below is HTML head tag. And below that are the errors that Chrome is showing. Does anyone understand why this is happening?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="NASA,JPL,near,earth,objects,asteroid,meteor,neo,neowise,api,opendata">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nearing Earth</title>

    <!-- Lines necessary for Bootstrap-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--My files-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="neoRules.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="neoStyles.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"/>
    <script src="https://nearingearth.com/neoFunctions.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>

      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="/js/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/js/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <![endif]-->
  </head>
```

Error 1:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://nearingearth.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'. This request has been
>   blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Error 2:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
>       at bootstrap.min.js:6

Answer (score 0):

neoFunctions.js is loading jquery without SSL. It's nothing to do with your HTML. I'd maybe recommend downloading neoFunctions.js and modifying the script to replace instances of http:// with https:// and host it on your own server.